# Kotlin Spring Boot TestRestTemplate and OAuth2 Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I've been trying to write a Kotling Spring Boot test utilizing `TestRestTemplate` to call an endpoint on my application that has a `PreAuthorize` annotation on it, but I am unable to propogate the `SecurityContext` with an authorized OAuth2 user. I keep getting the following exception:

> An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

I've tried a couple different things. Below, I'll depict the original setup, and what I've tried:

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMappting(/api/v1)
@PreAuthorize("@authorizationService.canDoThat()") // Some logic to compare request to backend DB. Test does not hit this method
class SomeController() {
   ...
   ...

   @PutMapping(/update)
   fun update(@RequestBody request) {
     // Some logic to update something (test doesn't hit this part)
   }
}
```

**Test**

```
@Test
fun `update`() {
   val url = "http://localhost:${port}${basePath}/update"

   val headers = HttpHeaders()
   val body = HttpEntity(
      UpdateRequest(
         // The request object
      ), headers
   )

   val response = restTemplate.exchange(
        url,
        HttpMethod.PUT,
        body,
        typeReference<SomeResponseType>()
    )
}
```

**Test using WithMockUser**

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(username = "username", password = "password", authorities = ["SCOPE_write"])
fun `update`() {
   val url = "http://localhost:${port}${basePath}/update"

   val headers = HttpHeaders()
   val body = HttpEntity(
      UpdateRequest(
         // The request object
      ), headers
   )

   val response = restTemplate.exchange(
        url,
        HttpMethod.PUT,
        body,
        typeReference<SomeResponseType>()
    )
}
```

**Test manually setting context**

```
@Test
fun `update`() {
   val url = "http://localhost:${port}${basePath}/update"

   val jwt = Jwt(
         "token-value",
         Instant.now(),
         Instant.now().plusSeconds(60),
         mapOf("Authorization" to "Bearer token-value"),
         mapOf("someClaim" to someClaimValue)
   )
   val authorities = setOf(GrantedAuthority { "SCOPE_write" })
   val oauthAuthentication = JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities)

   // Set security context
   val context: SecurityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext()
   context.authentication = oauthAuthentication
   SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context)

   val headers = HttpHeaders()
   val body = HttpEntity(
      UpdateRequest(
         // The request object
      ), headers
   )

   val response = restTemplate.exchange(
        url,
        HttpMethod.PUT,
        body,
        typeReference<SomeResponseType>()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,it's hard to figure out why you are using `RestTemplate` instead of `MockMvc` or `WebTestClient` (would need your complete test class for that). Is it an end-to-end test?

If writing an end-to-end test, you should be fetching the JWT from the authorization server: if you build it yourself, it will probably not pass validation (JWTs are signed with a private key on the authorization server and
JWT decoder checks this signature using the public key). In that case, nothing in the Authorization will be mocked, the identity is just the one served by the authorization server.

If writing unit (`@WebMvcTest`) or integration (`@SpringBootTest`) tests, then you should be using `MockMvc` or `WebTestClient` instead of `RestTemplate`. In that case, use an annotation, `MockMvc` request post processor or `WebTestClient` mutator, building the right type of `Authentication`

Second, `@WithMockUser` is putting a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` instance in test security context, when you probably want a `JwtAuthenticationToken` (would need your complete security configuration to be sure). You should be using `@WithMockJwtAuth` from [those libs I created](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) to build `JwtAuthentication token` (test tooling provided by spring-security-test for JWTs is limited to MockMvc and WebTestClient).

I suggest you take the time to read [this Baeldung article I wrote](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control).